# Hive query failed with vectorized Enable

Tags: hadoop, hive

[image: Describe table output is attached]  I am running a simple select query on hive

```
select * from orc_card_view where properties_et_year =2018 and properties_et_month=1 and properties_et_day=14 and properties_item_language='hi'
```

but its failed with below exception

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task: attempt_1513655378374_62300_m_000075_0 - exited : java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorMapOperator.process(VectorMapOperator.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:170)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.set(Text.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.expressions.VectorExpressionWriterFactory$6.writeValue(VectorExpressionWriterFactory.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.expressions.VectorExpressionWriterFactory$VectorExpressionWriterBytes.writeValue(VectorExpressionWriterFactory.java:272)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorFileSinkOperator.getRowObject(VectorFileSinkOperator.java:89)
```

after i disable vectorization

```
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=false;
```

It executed successfully. Please help me understanding what can be the cause of this issue.

Comment: can you do `describe table` and show the output here? Note that [`vectorized execution is only supported for ORC tables`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Vectorized+Query+Execution)

Comment: Its a orc table only. i have attached describe table output.